# Flume: No errors thrown but flume fails to transfer the file completely

Tags: apache, hadoop, flume

I've been working on flume from the last 2-3 weeks. I faced a new situation which im unaware of how to resolve.

Flow: using a basic flow, spoolDir -> fileChannel -> HDFS

No extra parameters set in the .conf file

File size that i'm trying to transfer: 1.4GB

Situation: the agents starts fine, the file transfer starts fine, the file in source gets renamed to .COMPLETED, the complete file is not getting transfered to HDFS, no errors/exceptions are being thrown. I ran the same adhoc several times i found that out of the 1.4 gigs only ~169Mb is getting transfered. Seems weird !

Any suggestions? Any solutions? any hypotheses?

Comment: Can you show your config?

Comment: We are using the following flow:
spoolDir-> AvroSinks(2)->AvroSource(2)->HDFSSink(2)

Non default parameters in conf:
Tier1:
spool_source_batchsize=1000 
avro_sinks_batchsize=500 
channel_capacity=1000000

Tier2:
HDFS_sinks_batchsize=500 
channel_capacity=1000000

It is definitely a problem with the batch sizes/capacity i configured the agent for. Can you just guide me where am i going wrong with the batch-sizes approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How long did you wait?
Give it an hour and you may see something.

It's possible you have a corrupt fileChannel and it need some time to clean it up.

What version of Flume, btw?

Comment: I'm using cdh4 flume-ng, I waited for some time, but i didn't see any file transfer happenning, ill cross check it again

Basically what i observed was when we tuned the batch sizes and channel capacities to some other values other than default we faced this issue, with the default values the file was getting transferred just fine.

The tuned parameter values which we used were:
spool_source_batchsize=1000
avro_sinks_batchsize=500
channel_capacity=1000000
hdfs_sinks_batchsize=500

Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some more data to the file and wait for some time. Anything interesting in the logs?

Also make sure you have enough space left on your HDFS.

Comment: Basically what i observed was when we tuned the batch sizes and channel capacities to some other values other than default we faced this issue, with the default values the file was getting transferred just fine.

The tuned parameter values which we used were:
spool_source_batchsize=1000
avro_sinks_batchsize=500
channel_capacity=1000000
hdfs_sinks_batchsize=500

Where am i going wrong?